# Error in creating map-reduce job while installing oozie

Tags: oozie

Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 4. Exception = Connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check oozie service running by typing

```
   oozie admin -oozie http://OOZIE_IP:11000/oozie -status
```

if it doesnt show `System mode: NORMAL`, oozie is not started correctly

2) set in  `core-site.xml` in hadoop config ,

```
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
    <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
```

Hope this works

Comment: when i check the status it is giving the same error. I have done the configuration in hadoop core-site.xml already.

Comment: can you post the command which you tried with the full error log in /var/log/oozie/oozie.log

Comment: /var/log-where is /var

Comment: It seems oozie is not started yet.
run
`$OOZIE_HOME/bin/oozied.sh run &`
and post me the logs

Comment: when i run oozied it says "ERROR: Oozie could not be started

REASON: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils"

Comment: I solved this error by placing the hadoop jar files in  server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: But when I create a mapreduce workflow using the command " sudo -u oozie ./bin/oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config /home/wcbdd/apache/oozie-4.1.0/examples/target/oozie-examples-4.1.0-examples/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run" it fails with the error  "Error: E0902 : E0902: Exception occured: [Call to ubuntu/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
" Please help me with this.

Comment: try this and print the output `oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status`

Comment: While creating oozie using sharelib command "sudo -u oozie ./bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000 -locallib oozie-sharelib-4.1.0.tar.gz" it is failing with the error "Error: E0902: Exception occured: [Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]". Please help me with this. But my oozie server is running.